# Listbox with javascript action not posting values

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following form:

```
<form name='progObj_form' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='processpage.php'>
<select name='manageObj[]' id='objectives'  multiple="multiple">
<option value=0>there are no objectives for this program</option>
</select><br />
<a href='#nogo' onclick="delItem(objectives,0,'objEditBtn')" class='shiftOpt'>delete selected</a><br />
<input name='newObjective' type='text' id='newObjective'/>
<input name='addNew' type='button' onclick="AddItem(newObjective.value,6,'objectives','objEditBtn');" value='add objective'/>
<input name="passProgID" type="hidden" value="1" /><br />
<input name="objectiveEdit" id="objEditBtn" type="submit" value="save changes" disabled=disabled/>
</form>
```

that allows data (objectives in this case) to be added and deleted from a list box.  That all works well but for some reason the updated listbox values aren't being passed to the process page.

I'm catching the data like so (simplified):

```
if (isset($_POST['objectiveEdit'])){
$progID=$_POST['passProgID'];
 for ($v=1;$v<count($_POST['manageObj']);$v++){
   $value=$_POST['manageObj'][$v];
   $sqlObj="INSERT INTO progObjective (progID,objective,objectiveOrder) VALUES ($progID,$value,$v)";
   $result = mssql_query($sqlObj,$linkProbation) or die('Query failed: '.$sqlObj);  
 }//end for ($a=0;$a<count($_POST['manageObj']);$a++)   
$objMsg=print_r($_POST['manageObj']).$sqlObj;       
}//end if (isset($_POST['objectiveEdit'])
```

For `$objMsg`, I get a response of `1` and the array doesn't print because ostensibly, it's empty which means that it also doesn't enter the for loop.

I can include the javascript as well but started with just this for simplicity since I'm probably just overlooking something obvious?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out!  There's no array because there are no selections made!  I updated the submit button to call a SELECT ALL function and now it's all good.

```
 <input name="objectiveEdit" id="objEditBtn" type="submit" value="save changes" onclick="selectAll('objectives',true)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Option elements are never sent to the server. Only the `value` of the selected option will be sent.

In your case, something like `manageObj=x` will be sent to the server, where `x` is the `value` of the `option` element that is selected by the user. It is possible that you misunderstand the `[]` when it's used in a `name` attribute.

You should try to find a different method if you want to send the objectives created by the user to the server. You could store the data in hidden `input`s for example.

Comment: I have a similar list box - it allows users to select items from one list and move/save it to a second list.  The process page is the same and I guess I thought it should work the same for this

Comment: I'm capturing the text entered and passing that as the value (for the other I captured an id#).  Since this also includes the ability to sort the option list (left that part out to simplify) I'm using the index number (or trying to) as the orderNumber.

Comment: So I finally figured it out!  There's no array because there are no selections made!  I updated the submit button to call a SELECT ALL function and now it's all good.

     `<input name="objectiveEdit" id="objEditBtn" type="submit" value="save changes" onclick="selectAll('objectives',true)" />`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review and offer input, @bažmegakapa!

Comment: @jlisham I am still unsure whether I understand exactly what you're doing, but I'm glad you solved it. Is that a multiple `select`? Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this question can be resolved.

Comment: yes it's multiple select - users can add/delete/re-sort objectives, so they all need to captured since the index is saved as the sort order. I finally determined that if I had one selected, the array was created and then it was short work to the solution (and less banging my head against the wall)

Comment: @jlisham There should be an `Answer Your Question` button around here somewhere. Please use that.

Answer (score -1):

name='**manageObj[]**' - shouldn't that be name='**manageObj**' ?

Comment: That won't change anything in this example.

Comment: brackets aren't allowed in element id's or names - it's an error to use them like that.

Comment: Please show me the relevant parts of the spec, because I haven't found that part where it says it's not allowed (hint: it is not there).

Comment: From the spec - ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([ A-Za-z ]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([ 0-9 ]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

[HTML 4 spec 6.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata)

Comment: This is the good old HTML4 spec, according to which you are right about the [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) attribute which is defined as [`NAME`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name). On the other hand the [`name` attribute of form elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-INPUT) is defined as [`CDATA`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata), so the latter CAN include `[` and `]` characters. The HTML5 spec is much more forgiving about `id` either.

Comment: @web_bod: the brackets allow multiple responses to be captured in an array and picked up via POST. So for instance, in a form: `name='$field_name[]'` can be captured in a loop as `for ($a=0;$a<count($_POST['field_name']);$a++){ echo $_POST['field_name'][$a];}`
as you can see from this example - the [] are not actually part of the field name, which is probably why they're not allowed to BE part of the name.